# IOS app Performance is too slow for parse data with swiftyjson

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, swifty-json

I created app with swift and i used swiftyjson for it. But when i parse images it's a little bit slow how can i improve speed of this. Could you help me about it? I'll share my code in the below thank you.

```
func parseJSON() {



        let path : String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonFile", ofType: "json") as String!
        let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
        let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
        var Name = readableJSON[passedValue,"Product","Ad"]

        NumberofRow = readableJSON[passedValue].count




        for i in 1...NumberofRow {
            var Person = "Product"
            Person += "\(i)"
            var Name = readableJSON[passedValue][Person]["Ad"].string as String!

            var Age = readableJSON[passedValue][Person]["Fiyat"].string as String!

             var Image1 = readableJSON[passedValue][Person]["URL"].string as String!


            NamesArray.append(Name)
            AgeArray.append(Age)
            Imagearray.append (Image1)

        }


    }
```

Comment: Forget SwiftyJSON or any other wrapper/framework. For now, nothing is faster than Foundation's NSJSONSerialization for deserializing JSON data.

Comment: But i don't know how to parse data with NSJSONSerialization also as i know foundation not supported get image from url

Comment: You cannot parse images and parsing JSON is usually very fast and is done by the system framework (so, you don't do it yourself either). I suspect there's some misconception. You should clarify what your problem is actually.

Comment: I have json data and images like url i get url from json and assigned to image view. But while i am waiting to upload images is too slow for me i need to make it faster

Comment: In a JSON (which is simply structured text), a "URL" will be represented as a JSON _String_. This URL string must be _properly_ encoded to be used in system frameworks which require an URL argument. You can use  [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/) to parse the JSON and get a _representation_ of that JSON which is a NSDictionary or a NSArray containing other JSON representations, e.g. Strings, Booleans, JSON Objects and JSON Array etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can  call function `parseJSON` in background thread and after it's completion return back to main thread (to update UI accordingly or something else).

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    // Perform data parsing
    parseJSON()

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        // Update UI on main thread
    })
})
```

If you would like to try this approach, I would recommend you to use open-source frameworks for easier work with GCD. For example https://github.com/duemunk/Async. If you use this framework, you can write as simple as following.

```
Async.background {
    // Perform data parsing
    parseJSON()
}.main {
    // Update UI on main thread
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what i wanted for =)